# Loading results of form into specified DIV

Tags: forms, html, target

I am trying to target a specific div with the results of a form post.
I have found the below code, but am unclear on where the URL for the page that handles the form data is specified.  Any help greatly appreciated.

```
$("form1").submit(function() {
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(html) {
        $("#someDiv").html(html);
    });
    return false; // prevent normal submit
});
```

For example, I want to send `form id="form1"` to somepage.php, and have somepage.php displayed into `div id=someDiv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that code-snippet, `$(this).attr("action")` is the URL: it's taken from the `action="..."` attribute of the `<form>` element. If, for whatever reason, you don't want to use that attribute to specify the URL, you can replace `$(this).attr("action")` with an explicit URL (as a string).

Comment: When I include the action="somepage.php" attribute to the <form>, it simply loads the result into the whole page (not into the DIV).

Comment: That means that the above code-snippet either is not being triggered, or else is not working, so the default `<form>` behavior is taking place. You haven't given enough information for me to help you debug it -- sorry.

Comment: The test page is located at : www.oil-soft.com/test3/divloader.html

Comment: You can't just put that code-snippet directly inside the `<script>...</script>`, because then the snippet will run before the page has fully loaded, and will try to add the on-submit-handler to the form before the form actually exists. You need to put the code-snippet inside an on-load-handler. See http://api.jquery.com/load-event/.

Comment: AHHHhh! Got it. Thanks so much, and pardon my ignorance!

Comment: This leads to the question of how to apply this same type handler to a form to be created in the future inside a div as the result of loading that div in the future. I thought it would warrant its own thread: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203771/adding-handler-to-form-inside-div-in-the-future

Answer (score 0):

It is defined in the action attribute of your form tag

Comment: When I include the action="somepage.php" attribute to the <form>, it simply loads the result into the whole page (not into the DIV).

Comment: try event.preventDefault(); instead of return false; // prevent normal submit. So your modified code should be .submit(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); });