# Adding handler to form inside div, in the future

Tags: events, html, event-handling, jquery

I am using the following code to direct the results from a form to a specific div.

```
$(window).load(function () {
  $("#form1").submit(function() {
      $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(html) {
        $("#resultsDiv").html(html);
      });
     return false; // prevent normal submit
  });
});
```

How can I apply this (or any) handler to future forms that may be created within an updated div ( with new yet to created content inserted into the div at some point in the future)?

I have looked at the .on  but I do not see an event for the updating or reloading of a div.

I have tried adding a similar function to the above, but replacing (window) with ("#thefutureDivID"), but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to add the handler is right after you know the element exists. So, right after this line:

```
$("#resultsDiv").html(html);
```

you can add your code that references `$("#thefutureDivID")`.

Comment: Hmm...In my case I have a form (form1) inside one div who's results show up in another div (resultsDiv). If the results (which are now the new contents of resultsDiv) contain another form, and I want the results of this new form to also appear within resultsDiv, I assumed I could use the same initial function as long as the form ID was the same. Apparently this is not the case, as the results reload the whole page as if the function is not being triggered.

Comment: The `id="..."` attribute is required to be unique on a page. You can't meaningfully have multiple elements with the same ID.